# How come I can't accept my answer to my question that no one else answered?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

Back in July I learned about Compass framwork leveraging BluePrint CSS framework and SASS based on top of the work done by HAML. I asked a question about any [developers using it in the ASP.NET world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214494/using-compass-on-windows-with-visual-studio-2008-c-and-asp-net). Never received any posts on it, come this month I was able to devote the time to learning it for myself and posted the answer last week. However I still am not able to accept the answer.

Am I missing something that's keeping me from accepting my own answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set up a bounty? If you set up a bounty and the bounty expires without an accepted answer, that question can never have an accepted answer.

Comment: Is there a particularly compelling reason for this?  I can see not allowing the OP of a question with a bounty to accept an answer after the bounty period that was given while the bounty was still in effect.  However, if someone answers the question after the bounty period is over, it seems like it would be good to allow that answer to be marked as accepted.

Comment: @tnorthcutt, I can't seem to get to the blog (blog.stackoverflow.com) this minute, but I believe this behavior was announced as part of the release of the bounty feature.

Comment: Valid point, however I checked the history of the particular question and cannot find proof of an expired bounty. There is a answer to the bounty question on MSO but I can't find the actual question. I do recall I answered it thought :(

Comment: There was indeed a bounty that expired to this question.

Comment: Still seems like a bug with this being a reason